# grub can't find CentOS 7

Tags: ubuntu, centos, lvm, grub

My desktop was tri-booting between Ubuntu 2.04, CentOS 6, and Windows. I installed CentOS 7 in the space that CentOS 6 used, but update-grub doesn't result in the new CentOS showing up. I can only think there's some issue with the version or the way LVM is used by CentOS 7 that Ubntu doesn't agree with. Any thoughts?

Comment: Does your GRUB maybe detect a `RedHat` entry?  Just wondering as I think the `/etc/lib/os-probes/mounted/90linux-distro` file reads for OSes with `/etc/redhat-release` which is what CentOS has.

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 7 uses grub2.  Ubuntu 12.04 uses grub.  I used the CentOS DVD to install grub2 on the boot partition, and all is well!